# How create to script(.bat) to open text file form D drive (windows 10)

Tags: batch-file

I need to create batch file to open my notepad++ file  which located in D drive.

can anyone please help with  commands

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you open notepad++ and a file for it from command-line:

```
start notepad++ <filename>
```

If the file is located at D, then:

```
start notepad++ D:\yourfile
```

Make sure notepad++ is in your PATH. To convert this into a batch, you will just need to put this command into a batch file.